# Как настроить Android.mk и Application.mk для использования сторонних .SO в Анроиде?

Tags: android, android-ndk, jni, makefile

У меня имеется библиотека использующая нативные функции (JNI) для работы с серийным портом. В линуксе и винде всё отлично работало. При подключении JAR как зависимости в Android при первом обращении к нативной функции появляется ошибка вызова метода, причина которой `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Я так понял, что андроид требует или перекомпиляции .so и .dll из исходников или просто вызова System.loadLibrary("serial"); где-нибудь в static-блоке.

Второе, что, как я понял, важно, правильно прописать параметры в файлах Android.mk и Application.mk. типа там должны быть описаны все внешние нативные модули. В таком случае в каких папках их создавать? Что в них писать? [Это](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html) и [это](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html) смотрел, ничего не понял.